# Login Screen Extremely Dim on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, screen, brightness

`I have a Nvidia GTX 1060 3gb graphics card.`
Desktop PC

I've read article after article and I cannot find a solution for this fix. I asked other desktop users who run ubuntu and most of them don't have this issue, so I'm assuming it's related to my graphics card?

I have literally no idea what to do. The login screen when i swipe up from lock is so dim i can barely see my username.

Help would be much appreciated!